# Kubeflow kale failed to connect Rok module

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am trying to integrate kubeflow kale in jupyterlab. For that, I have installed the recommeded package using the below command

```
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install \
    --upgrade pip \
    urllib3==1.24.3 \
    jupyter-client==6.1.5 \
    nbformat==5.0.2 \
    six==1.15 \
    numpy==1.17.3 \
    jupyter-console==6.0.0 \
    jupyterlab==1.1.1 \
    jupyterthemes \
    xgboost \
    kubeflow-fairing==1.0.0 \
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]kubeflow-kale

# Kale installation
RUN jupyter labextension install kubeflow-kale-launcher
```

The docker image was build successfully. When I run this jupyterlab in the cluster I am getting the below error

```
Details: Rok Gateway Client module not found
```

Do I need to install any other plugins?

Please help anyone to fix this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should to install ROK on Your Kubernetes cluster.
Without ROK you can't use it